# angularjs: how to disable 'multiple' when it is bind to scope (upload file)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Consider [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WgZZM/3/) jsfiddle. What I'm trying here is that I want to be able to toggle multiple on and off. To do this I created an input field as follows

```
<input type="file" multiple="{{multi}}">
```

The problem is that no matter what I put into multi

```
$scope.multi = false ;
```

you can still pick multiple files. Any suggestions how this can be fix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directive is a right way , as usual:

```
.directive("myMultiple",function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope,element){
            scope.$watch("multi",function(n,o){               
                if(scope.multi ){
                   element.attr("multiple","multiple");
                } else {
                   element.removeAttr("multiple"); 
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WgZZM/5/

Answer (score 2):

Write an attribute directive which adds or removes the whole multiple attribute of the element it's added to.

This directive can be tied to a boolean model attribute.